# Remove a sentence which starts with word "mark" and ends with ";"

Tags: linux, scripting, sed, awk

I am having 100's of files that contain sentence that starts with **mark** and ends with **semicolon(;)**.

```
eg: mark is driving a car;
```

i need to remove every sentence starts with **mark** and end with "**;**"

How to do  this  using **sed** or simmilar tools.

i have used sed to replace pattern but dont know how to delete patterns.

Comment: Can you guarantee that each sentence will be on a single line, ie, that no matching sentence will contain a line break?

Comment: @MadHatter yes all are on a single line.

Comment: For the future, simple regex/`sed` questions like this are really better suited to [unix.se], unless they're in some way related to professional system administration (per the SF [FAQ]). I know it seems like a strange/arbitrary distinction, but since [unix.SE] got created we like to encourage people to use it :)

Comment: @voretaq7 thanx...next time i will use that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all matching sentences are all on a single line, and you say you're already familiar with sed, then it's just a special case of using `sed` to replace one pattern with another, in this case replacing with nothing:

```
sed -e 's/mark.*;//'
```

Comment: Asker wants to delete the line - your solution will just make it blank.

Comment: That's not what he asked; he asked to remove every matching sentence, not to delete every line on which such a sentence occurs.  I agree that, from his comment on your answer, the latter appears to be what he wants, but it's not what he asked for!

Comment: I suppose that is open to interpretation: `i have used sed to replace pattern but dont know how to delete patterns`. I read that is he is OK with find/replace, but not find/delete.

Comment: Fair enough.  As you can tell from my answer, I read it as "I know how to replace A with B, but I have not realised that deleting string A is equivalent to replacing it with `''`".  There is also the unaddressed issue of what the OP wants done with a line that says `steve is driving a bus; mark is driving a car;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `d` in `sed` to delete a line:

```
$ echo -e "mark is driving a car;\nbob is driving a car;" | sed -e '/^mark/d'
bob is driving a car;
```

Comment: i dont want to replace content instead delete that line starts with that string

Comment: Which is exactly what my example shows? `mark is driving a car;` is no longer in the output, but `bob is driving a car;` is (the `\n` in the echo means "new line").

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed:

```
sed -e '/^mark.*;$/d'
```

This removes everything starting with "mark" and ending with ";".